# Why does the castle turn blue?

Tags: rogue-legacy

It has happened to me, twice. I enter the castle and the walls are blue. In which circumstances does this happens? Does it have any effect, or is it just aesthetic?
[image: My screenshot in a blue castle]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is caused by playing a descendant with the trait **The One**.

The trait is purely aesthetic and does not have other effects.

Source: http://rogue-legacy.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Traits